# What is the fastest way to do inverse multi-hot encoding in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the fastest way to an inverse "multi-hot" (like one-hot with multiple simultaneous categories) operation on a large DataFrame?

I have the follow DataFrame:

```
id  type_A  type_B  type_C
 1       1       1       0
 2       0       1       0
 3       0       1       1
```

The operation would give:

```
id   type
 1 type_A
 1 type_B
 2 type_B
 3 type_B
 3 type_C
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `melt` and `query`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars='id', value_vars=['type_A', 'type_B', 'type_C']).query('value == 1')

   id variable  value
0   1   type_A      1
3   1   type_B      1
4   2   type_B      1
5   3   type_B      1
8   3   type_C      1
```

With correct column names:

```
df = (
    df.melt(id_vars='id', 
            value_vars=['type_A', 'type_B', 'type_C'],
            var_name='type')
      .query('value == 1')
      .drop(columns='value')
)

   id    type
0   1  type_A
3   1  type_B
4   2  type_B
5   3  type_B
8   3  type_C
```

Answer (score 2):

melt should be the normal way to achieve this

```
yourdf=df.melt('id').loc[lambda x : x['value']==1]
   id variable  value
0   1   type_A      1
3   1   type_B      1
4   2   type_B      1
5   3   type_B      1
8   3   type_C      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with [`.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html) which uses matrix multiplication with the columns helped by  [`series.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) which is new in version `0.25+`:

```
m = df.set_index('id')
m.dot(m.columns+',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',').explode().reset_index(name='type')
```

---

```
   id    type
0   1  type_A
1   1  type_B
2   2  type_B
3   3  type_B
4   3  type_C
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
new_df = (df.set_index('id')
            .where(lambda x: x.eq(1))
            .stack()
            .rename_axis(['id','type'])
            .reset_index()[['id','type']] )
print(new_df)
   id    type
0   1  type_A
1   1  type_B
2   2  type_B
3   3  type_B
4   3  type_C
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.melt(id_vars='id', ).query('value == 1').drop(columns='value').rename(columns={"variable":"type"})
```

desired result:

```
    id  type
0   1   type_A
3   1   type_B
4   2   type_B
5   3   type_B
8   3   type_C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all zeros with `NaN` and `stack`. By stacking all `NaN` values are dropped. Than you can get the `MultiIndex` and convert it into a data frame:

```
df = df.set_index('id') # set 'id' to index if necessary

df.replace(0, np.nan).stack().index.to_frame(index=False, name=['id', 'type'])
```

Output:

```
   id    type
0   1  type_A
1   1  type_B
2   2  type_B
3   3  type_B
4   3  type_C
```